# Zip Deployment fails with "Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Disk quota exceeded"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am getting an error when deploying Azure functions using zip deploy to Azure. The error I see in VSTS is not very detailed but it indicates that the zip deploy failed.

```
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.

##[error]To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : https://my-path/**/trace

##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Internal Server Error (CODE: 500)
```

Looking at the default docker error dump I see more details. Apparently there is a disk quota issue, but I checked my storage account and it was only using 3GB out of 5000 GB.

The details from the deployment log can be found below:

```
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Disk quota exceeded
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.FindNextEntry(Byte* entryBufferPtr, Int32 bufferLength)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance..ctor(FileSystemWatcher watcher, SafeFileHandle inotifyHandle, String directoryPath, Boolean includeSubdirectories, NotifyFilters notifyFilters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__1_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Program.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Program.cs:line 25
/azure-functions-host/start.sh: line 28:    18 Aborted                 (core dumped) /azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost
```

What is the disk quota we are subject to when deploying AZ functions? I can't see any quotas in either the app service plan or the resource group. As I mentioned above, the storage account referenced by the function is far from capacity.

For reference the size of my application is only 13MB.

In the Azure portal I see the error message "System.Private.CoreLib: Disk quota exceeded" in a red banner in the overview pane.

This build has been running well for months. This issue started happening in the last few days. I believe we have seen it hapen very intermittently before, but currently it happens almost every time. If we are lucky we may get 1 in 10 deployments to go through.

The function app is a regular Linux function app in the premium (EP1) tier.

Comment: This seems to be an issue on Linux. Converting the function app to Windows fixed the issue.

Comment: You may add a reply and accept it as an answer, which will be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue on Linux. Converting the function app to Windows fixed the issue.